# Jest: Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: testing, jestjs, configuration, babeljs, babel-jest

I'm trying to configure jest/babel to do react component testing in my app. So far I'm facing some difficulties, in imports.
It throws this error:
[image: Reference]

Here is my `babel.config.json`:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ],
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

I've trying adding `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` and it brings different problems upon itself. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: We've run into this exact issue after upgrading Jest from v26 to v29. I'm working on a minimal repro here: https://github.com/eirikur-grid/jest-esm-issue-repro.

You might be able to work around this by using an older Jest version. 26 and 27 seem to work, whereas 28 and above exhibit this behaviour.